# Choosing different term orders for Groebner basis calculations in GAP

Tags: gap, computational-algebra, groebner-basis, quiver

I am using the QPA and GBNP packages in GAP to analyze path algebra quotients. I use the GBNP package for computing Groebner bases for the ideals in the path algebras, and the term orders for these bases are just computed automatically by the program.

> Is there a way to choose different term orders for the Groebner bases? If so, how do I do this?

In the [GBNP manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/gbnp/doc/manual.pdf) it says that users can use other orderings by using functions from the NMO extension to GBNP. However, I have not been able to find such an extension, and the documentation on this in the manual (reference [5]) seems to no longer be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the problem. The NMO manual seems to no longer be accessible online, however one can still access it through the GAP files on their computer (assuming they have installed GAP). In the GAP folder (at the time posting this I have gap-4.9.2), go to the following:

```
 gap-4.9.2/pkg/gbnp/doc/nmo
```

and there is a pdf file titled "manual", which is the NMO manual and contains information on creating different term orders.

Comment: How does **how to access the manual** become an _acceptable_ answer to the question **how to change GB order?**